# Tunneling with tun2socks to bypass Iran's internet censorship

Tags: networking, command-line, server, ssh

I am a beginner, I was trying to tunnel between my computer to `VPS1` (which has restricted internet due to Iran government policy) and `VPS2` (From an Europan provider). Just rented an Ubuntu 20 VPS server from the Iranian provider (`VPS1`). I tried installing and configuring `shadowsocks` and `v2ray` and use `tun2socks` using these commands:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4



apt update

apt install shadowsocks-libev tmux

apt install vsftpd

apt install unzip

wget https://github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks/releases/download/v2.4.1/tun2socks-linux-amd64.zip

unzip tun*
```

I used this config for tun2socks (https://github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks/wiki/Examples):

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun7

ip addr add 198.18.0.1/15 dev tun7

ip link set dev tun7 up
```

and then :

```
wget https://github.com/shadowsocks/v2ray-plugin/releases/download/v1.3.2/v2ray-plugin-linux-amd64-v1.3.2.tar.gz

tar xf v2ray*
```

Then I used this command:

```
ufw allow 80
```

I created this script as PEPE.json:

```
{
   "server":"0.0.0.0",
   "mode":"tcp_and_udp",
   "server_port":80,
   "password":"passsssssssss",
   "timeout":60,
   "method":"chacha20-ietf-poly1305",
   "nameserver":"8.8.8.8",
   "plugin":"v2ray-plugin_linux_amd64",
   "plugin_opts":"server"
}
```

I ran the script :

```
ss-server -c PEPE.json -i tun7
```

and finally:

```
./tun2socks-linux-amd64 -device tun7 -proxy http://X.X.X.X:22
```

I put my VPS1 server IP and port as `X.X.X.X`

In the end, I could receive no connection at all. What did I do wrong? Do I have to tunnel between `VPS1` to `VPS2`(Europian VPS) using a specific command?
I did replace `X.X.X.X` with the `VPS2`  but still, nothing happened.

I would appreciate any help to solve my issue.

There is a video here showing the path I followed:

https://t.me/CyberNigga2/996

Comment: This exact question has been asked before and the answer has not changed. This is most likely illegal. See the info on this site https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @David If this has been answered, please provide a link to the duplicate so we can close it out as such. Also, if the solution doesn't work, the OP can explain why it doesn't apply. The rules don't say anything about illegal activity, particularly with respect to laws in jurisdictions that don't apply to Stackexchange. Circumventing government censorship is a common topic on almost all SE sites.

Comment: @David He just wanted to tunnel from VPS1 in a restricted environment to VPS2. How is this question against the rules?

Stackexchange is getting weird

Comment: If you find the answer, please share it here too.